# Do WebSockets imply process sticky behavior behind arbitrary infrastructure?

Tags: websocket, load-balancing

I'm aware the current ideal is the RESTful design, where each individual (HTTP[S]) request can go to any server process anywhere, and still work, regardless of any load balancing, scaling, fail-over etc. This is because all state is either kept on the web client, or being in some sort of data base.

Most of our application runs that way, but there are *some* functionalities that need stateful operation in the server process. We have complex, large and expensive to compute in-memory data models that are then interactively explored and manipulated by the user, i.e., via further requests/messages. These huge models cannot be efficiently persisted via data base on a request by request basis, nor can they (or should they) be sent to the web client.

Therefore I'm looking for a design, where a web client, once it has initiated such a functionality, remains connected to the same server process, regardless of how complex the infrastructure in front of it is.

Am I right to assume that connecting a WebSocket actually achieves that? It will "harpoon" through any of the buzzword tech, like ingress, load balancer, reverse proxy, container networking, competing pre-forked servers, etc. and permanently pin the one server process that happens to do the WebSocket upgrade, and then stay tethered for good, subject to successful pings and pongs, perhaps for hours?

Except for that client/process pair to be tied together, it will still not stand in the way of doing load balancing, scaling and whatnot for plain HTTP[S] traffic and for any new WebSocket connections, right?

More importantly, the configuration of all that infrastructure in front need not be aware of this "process stickiness", it is implicitly guaranteed by virtue of the WebSocket RFC so to speak, and therefore very likely also with tomorrow's tech, right?

Comment: Yes. It opens a connection to a server that holds the connection open and anything going back and forth is tied to that process, unless there’s some load balancer for websocket messages built to not make it so. So theoretically it might not go through all the stuff in front of it, but I can’t think of any reason why anyone would try to load balance websocket messages without telling you.